# How to check if a file line contains only the string searched?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a file with multiple line:

```
En;15;
Vu;
US;32;
```

I need to check if the string `VU` is contained so I did:

```
string text = @"En;15;
Vu;
US;32;"

var exist = text.Contains("Vu");
```

this will return `true` but I need to check also if the line of `Vu` contains only `Vu` or other contents as the other lines. How can I do this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

if  the line contains also other element should return false

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you give us a few examples of input and expected output?

Comment: check my update

Comment: @oÆÞ doesn't my answer resolve your problem?

Comment: Your description is very vague. 1) Is it case sensitive? Your question says `VU`, but you search for `Vu`. 2) The 2nd line contains more than `Vu`, it also contains an `;`. Does that count as "other contents"?

Comment: @Sentry 1. it's not case sensitive, that's a typo error 2. the ; isn't important, specificy only the end of the content itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your string into an array and that you will be able to separate all the lines into a separated indexes in the string array using the `Split()` method
with the separator '\n' that represents a new line:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string stringfromfile = @"En;
                            15;
                            Vu;
                            US;
                            32;";

    string[] ar = stringfromfile.Split('\n');

    // remove ";" character and fix white space for safety
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
    {
        ar[i] = ar[i].Replace(";","").Trim();
    }

    if (ar.Contains("Vu"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FALSE");
    }

    foreach (var itm in ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(itm);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: this code working for you? for me don't

Comment: yes it is working, show you complete code if you want help.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand, I have a file with a string `Vu`, your code simply remove all the ; but at the end does the same stuff of my code

Comment: the code is setting each line in a separate index of the array so you are able to access each row distinctly...to understand it better see the loop that prints to the console i have added.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your input a "newline" is "\n", and assuming that things in a line are separated by ";", then:

1) break the text into separate lines
2) for each line, break the line into pieces separated by ";"
3) for each broken-line, check each piece and see if `Vu` is there
4) ..and if it is, hey you found it
5) ..and if that broken-line had just 1 piece, hey, it was single Vu

Bits of code:

1)
    @"text
    that
    has
    lines".Split("\n")   ==> array of 4 lines

2)
    "linethat;has;pieces".Split(";")   ===> array of 3 pieces

3) "for each" is a `foreach` loop. You will need one for lines, and one for pieces. One inside the other.

4) Split removes the separator, so ";" wont show up in a piece, so `if(piece == "Vu")`

5) "pieces" is array-of-strings, so `if(pieces.Length==1)` means that the line had a single piece

Now you have all bits, just use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching very simply for "\nVu\n" so it would look something little like:

```
var exist = text.Contains("\nVu\n");
```

This would find all cases except for the special cases of first and last line, and is more efficient than splitting the string into an array.

And as @quetzalcoatl said

> ..and first and last line can be covered by .StartsWith("Vu\n") and .EndsWith("\nVu")..

Comment: ..and first and last line can be covered by `.StartsWith("Vu\n")` and `.EndsWith("Vu\n")||.EndsWith("Vu")`.. I wrote exactly that option as a comment.. wonder why my comment disapperared, but oh well whatever ;)

Comment: Sorry to hear that @quetzalcoatl. These easy questions are quite popular I guess... So maybe just some SO misshap